# scraping through python selenium or beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver, parsehub

i want to scrape the url below
https://turo.com/search?airportCode=EWR&customDelivery=true&defaultZoomLevel=11&endDate=04%2F05%2F2019&endTime=11%3A00&international=true&isMapSearch=false&itemsPerPage=200&location=EWR&locationType=Airport&maximumDistanceInMiles=30&sortType=RELEVANCE&startDate=03%2F05%2F2019&startTime=10%3A00

i want all the href link of the cars listed so that i can scrape forward 
but i am unable to get it

please help

Comment: Please share your code and explain what isn't working

Answer (score 2):

You can pull in the json response with the query and work with that:

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

base_url = 'https://turo.com'

url = 'https://turo.com/api/search?'
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Host': 'turo.com',
'Referer': 'https://turo.com/search'}

params = {
'airportCode': 'EWR',
'customDelivery': 'true',
'defaultZoomLevel': '11',
'endDate': '04/05/2019',
'endTime': '11:00',
'international': 'true',
'isMapSearch': 'false',
'itemsPerPage': '200',
'location': 'EWR',
'locationType': 'Airport',
'maximumDistanceInMiles': '30',
'sortType': 'RELEVANCE',
'startDate': '03/05/2019',
'startTime': '10:00'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
data = response.json()

search_id = data['searchId']
print (search_id)

for ele in data['list']:
    link = ele['vehicle']['url']
    print (base_url + link)




links_list = [ base_url + ele['vehicle']['url'] for ele in data['list'] ]




# If you want to Manipulate a table of the data
df = json_normalize(data['list'])
```

**Output:**

```
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/ford-mustang/385739
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/mazda-cx-9/84783
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/chatham-township/mercedes-benz-s-class/439410
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/edgewater/bmw-3-series/360338
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/edgewater/mercedes-benz-s-class/528415
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/mercedes-benz-c-class/546598
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/wallington/bmw-3-series/523288
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/edgewater/mercedes-benz-c-class/402723
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/east-brunswick/dodge-charger/474370
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/dover/mini-cooper/562685
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/east-brunswick/dodge-challenger/245816
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/city-of-orange/bmw-3-series/441085
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/aberdeen-township/chevrolet-corvette/329734
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/montvale/nissan-rogue/551766
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/haledon/ford-mustang/527092
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/montvale/toyota-rav4/551789
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/wallington/bmw-3-series/506047
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/englewood/toyota-rav4/205796
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/audi-tt-rs/454914
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/newark/jeep-grand-cherokee/547858
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/scotch-plains/acura-mdx/494289
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/dodge-journey/371145
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/tesla-model-s/450268
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/ridgefield-park/bmw-m3/479442
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/edgewater/bmw-x3/509043
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/lodi/kia-sorento/535604
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/scotch-plains/bmw-x5/555187
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/west-new-york/audi-q5/317033
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/honda-cr-v/523284
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/old-bridge-township/acura-mdx/384309
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/pa/wind-gap/bmw-3-series/558761
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/toyota-rav4/442146
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/hillsborough-township/mercedes-benz-c-class/330064
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/audi-a8/518856
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/mount-olive-township/bmw-3-series/528020
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/il/lincolnwood/mercedes-benz-cls-class/207362
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/bmw-5-series/515357
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/newark/audi-a6/108287
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/montvale/audi-a3/552084
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/bmw-x6-m/325161
https://turo.com/rentals/minivans/nj/jersey-city/honda-odyssey/256481
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/dover/bmw-1-series/562679
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/fort-lee/audi-q7/437196
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/edgewater/jaguar-xf/528929
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/bmw-3-series/309937
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/bmw-1-series/517828
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/old-bridge-township/jeep-wrangler/506051
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/bmw-x5/533213
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/morristown/honda-pilot/310610
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/chevrolet-camaro/207528
https://turo.com/rentals/minivans/nj/jersey-city/honda-odyssey/506466
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/edgewater/acura-mdx/522686
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/bloomfield/porsche-911/153991
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/west-new-york/land-rover-range-rover-sport/295016
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/infiniti-fx/533200
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/bmw-x5/551272
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/newark/kia-sorento/554517
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/honda-cr-v/517423
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/rahway/jeep-grand-cherokee/410048
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/clifton/dodge-challenger/513745
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/bmw-z4/569205
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/union-city/acura-rdx/159384
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/roselle/chevrolet-impala/389132
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/newark/ford-edge/543229
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/wallington/bmw-3-series/560189
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/rahway/nissan-murano/491762
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/sayreville/ford-escape/561262
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/randolph/bmw-3-series/476134
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/dodge-charger/353789
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/bloomfield/land-rover-range-rover-sport/526192
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/hillsborough-township/infiniti-g-sedan/466276
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/edgewater/lexus-rx-350/455895
https://turo.com/rentals/trucks/nj/jackson/toyota-tundra/506040
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/tesla-model-3/458395
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/mercedes-benz-e-class/533931
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/monroe-township/bmw-x3/526846
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/roselle-park/volkswagen-tiguan/534144
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/pa/easton/mercedes-benz-glk-class/422203
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/bmw-3-series/543432
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/edison/infiniti-q50/559651
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/elizabeth/jeep-grand-cherokee/566712
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/edison/infiniti-q50/448312
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/rahway/toyota-highlander/524049
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/newark/ford-mustang/551401
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/montvale/porsche-macan/551814
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/hackensack/porsche-cayman/514871
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/city-of-orange/mercedes-benz-c-class/414725
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/east-brunswick/ford-flex/340268
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/burlington/tesla-model-s/316123
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/tesla-model-3/552630
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jackson/ford-explorer/534670
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/haledon/honda-insight/421898
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/elizabeth/bmw-5-series/548519
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/montvale/mercedes-benz-glc-class/552101
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/bmw-x5/357098
https://turo.com/rentals/trucks/nj/weehawken/ford-f-150/405386
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/audi-a4/541799
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/edgewater/jeep-wrangler/219798
https://turo.com/rentals/trucks/nj/montvale/ford-f-150/551838
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/little-falls/lexus-is-250/179987
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/old-bridge-township/maserati-granturismo-convertible/488496
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/jaguar-f-type/420320
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/east-brunswick/gmc-acadia/348063
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/garfield/mercedes-benz-e-class/500408
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/edison/mercedes-benz-c-class/315170
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/bayonne/mercedes-benz-cls-class/480787
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/hammonton/ford-mustang/534026
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/south-amboy/bmw-7-series/138755
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/bmw-i3/344512
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/pa/easton/pontiac-g3/343750
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/bmw-5-series/362079
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/montvale/bmw-4-series/551976
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/haledon/honda-civic/369357
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/phillipsburg/porsche-boxster/420778
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/city-of-orange/infiniti-qx30/427614
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/toyota-highlander/196708
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/mercedes-benz-glk-class/546930
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/elizabeth/mercedes-benz-e-class/473235
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/newark/volkswagen-jetta/297019
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/little-ferry/honda-cr-v/483880
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/mazda-3/379389
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/tesla-model-3/539962
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jackson/cadillac-cts/506062
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/ct/sharon/bmw-7-series/536091
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/east-orange/porsche-macan/467839
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/roselle/nissan-versa/473960
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/hoboken/mercedes-benz-e-class/533198
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/hillsborough-township/gmc-acadia/553441
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/lodi/tesla-model-3/568337
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/mazda-6/528355
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/west-new-york/mercedes-benz-e-class/544361
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/edison/gmc-terrain/416012
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/newark/ford-focus/284564
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/old-bridge-township/bmw-5-series/560039
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/linwood/toyota-camry/219654
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/honda-fit/429840
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/bmw-x5/429301
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/montvale/jaguar-f-pace/551780
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/elizabeth/ford-explorer/361114
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/infiniti-g37/69252
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/tesla-model-3/483663
https://turo.com/rentals/minivans/nj/linden/toyota-sienna/565755
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/dover/jeep-wrangler/273594
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/mercedes-benz-glk-class/147897
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/montvale/audi-q7/552088
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/montvale/nissan-altima/551762
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/bmw-3-series/382246
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/newark/chevrolet-malibu/337149
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/fairview/honda-accord/441008
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/pa/easton/ford-fiesta/324654
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/montvale/mercedes-benz-c-class/552099
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/west-new-york/land-rover-lr3/317945
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/montvale/bmw-4-series/551975
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/pa/lansdale/volvo-s80/502585
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/montvale/alfa-romeo-stelvio/567102
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/pa/easton/toyota-yaris/286270
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/hyundai-accent/406944
https://turo.com/rentals/minivans/nj/jackson/toyota-sienna/506024
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/land-rover-range-rover-evoque/253107
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/bloomfield/land-rover-range-rover-sport/307494
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/montvale/mercedes-benz-e-class/552109
https://turo.com/rentals/minivans/nj/newark/honda-odyssey/535200
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/ford-mustang/500739
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/elizabeth/toyota-rav4/503028
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/montvale/audi-a6/552092
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/paterson/honda-cr-v/312733
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/montvale/bmw-5-series/551973
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/teaneck/tesla-model-s/520126
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/little-falls/acura-mdx/222780
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/wallington/bmw-x3/440188
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/belleville/jeep-cherokee/501526
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/harrison/volkswagen-touareg/531531
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/ford-mustang/438281
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/roxbury-township/bmw-x1/562709
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/montvale/mercedes-benz-c-class/551803
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/pa/easton/nissan-versa/276913
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/city-of-orange/kia-sorento/101234
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/montvale/bmw-x5/551968
https://turo.com/rentals/minivans/pa/easton/toyota-sienna/215018
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/edgewater/hyundai-elantra-touring/476041
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/haledon/nissan-altima/318098
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/paterson/toyota-rav4/553455
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/union-city/hyundai-sonata/461816
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/montvale/jaguar-xe/551782
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/northvale/bmw-4-series/483229
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/harrison/audi-a5/518618
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/newark/chevrolet-camaro/409288
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/montvale/porsche-cayenne/551802
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/ct/west-haven/lexus-gx-460/557327
https://turo.com/rentals/trucks/nj/south-river/dodge-ram-1500/537439
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/hoboken/gmc-terrain/217576
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/mount-olive-township/chevrolet-cruze/392840
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/old-bridge-township/mercedes-benz-cls-class/488471
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/garfield/nissan-altima/355678
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/jersey-city/infiniti-qx60/454257
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/montvale/toyota-camry/551790
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/edgewater/volkswagen-jetta/519761
https://turo.com/rentals/suvs/nj/weehawken/chevrolet-tahoe/97631
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/elizabeth/honda-accord/524828
https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/montville/volkswagen-jetta/553559
```

Comment: the links should have search id included  link extracted should  be seen like https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/ford-mustang/385739?searchId=4NXeukCK

Comment: May ask why the search id needs to be included? Maybe I’m missing something, but I’m not seeing the difference between with or without the search ID if I go to the link.

Comment: when i tried to load page from the output above its shows nothing but the actual link has search id  when i open that link it open fine and one thing how can i run the above script its not running on my side

Comment: 1) how are you loading the page/link? And what do you mean "its shows nothing"? What is "it"? 2) i'm not sure how to answer that. you can the script in the terminal, you can run it through Python IDE like pycharm or spyder.

Comment: 1) its shows no details please see the link by browsing u will get it

Comment: so what can be changed to get it

Comment: depends what are you trying to pull from each link. There are still some endpoints to pull data.

Comment: the above output is fine but the only thing i want is the source id included

Comment: it's in the json object. `data['searchId']`. I added that into the code above

Comment: just append it. it's pretty basic operation to combine strings. I updated the code above to reflect that.

Comment: search id cannot be same for all links

Comment: Then you’re going to have to work out that issue, search through the json Object to see if/where it’s located. Or I can suggest, please post it as a new question because this is going beyond the scope of the original post of simply listing the links, which there is a solution to.  if you post a new question, you will receive attention from more people than just me to work out what it is as your desired output.

Comment: the output is https://turo.com//rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/ford-mustang/385739 the desired output must be:https://turo.com/rentals/cars/nj/jersey-city/ford-mustang/385739?searchId=-fCVfkbh

Comment: ah ok. it's because I had `base_url = 'https://turo.com/` just had to change that to `base_url = 'https://turo.com'`  I'm not convinced you need the searchId attached to the link because the site still loads for me correctly without it. But give the code above a try again.